# SQL Server + Dynamic Query 'Invalid Column Name'

Tags: sql

I am trying to execute the following dynamic query but I got an error: Invalid column name 'cat'

```
 DECLARE @SQLDelQuery AS NVARCHAR(1200)   
 DECLARE @MemberNames varchar(50)

 SET @MemberNames = 'cat'

      SET @SQLDelQuery = 'SELECT [Email] FROM [aspnet_Membership] am
      INNER JOIN [aspnet_Users] u
      ON (am.UserId = u.UserId)
      INNER JOIN [Member] m
      ON (am.UserId = m.UserId)
      WHERE u.UserName IN (' + @MemberNames + ')

  EXECUTE(@SQLDelQuery)
```

If I change it to the normal query I am fine:

```
SELECT [Email] FROM [aspnet_Membership] am
  INNER JOIN [aspnet_Users] u
  ON (am.UserId = u.UserId)
  INNER JOIN [Member] m
  ON (am.UserId = m.UserId)
  WHERE u.UserName IN ('cat')
```

Anyone can point out my error? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `cat` is a varchar you need to include single quotes around it and you need to place the closing parentheses for the `IN` clause inside of the sql string.

The new code will be:

```
DECLARE @SQLDelQuery AS NVARCHAR(1200)   
 DECLARE @MemberNames varchar(50)

 SET @MemberNames = 'cat'

      SET @SQLDelQuery = 'SELECT [Email] FROM [aspnet_Membership] am
      INNER JOIN [aspnet_Users] u
      ON (am.UserId = u.UserId)
      INNER JOIN [Member] m
      ON (am.UserId = m.UserId)
      WHERE u.UserName IN (''' + @MemberNames + ''')'

  EXECUTE(@SQLDelQuery)
```

See a [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9681) with the query string printed. This generates a query string like this:

```
SELECT [Email] 
FROM [aspnet_Membership] am 
INNER JOIN [aspnet_Users] u 
  ON (am.UserId = u.UserId) 
INNER JOIN [Member] m 
  ON (am.UserId = m.UserId) 
WHERE u.UserName IN ('cat') -- cat surrounded in single quotes
```

Comment: thank you bluefeet. it worked. i cant vote yet cos i need 50 points

Answer (score 2):

Your string:

```
WHERE u.UserName IN (' + @MemberNames + ')
```

will evaluate to:

```
WHERE u.UserName IN (cat)
```

because the apostrophes you have are just encapsulating the string, and there are no extra apostrophes around the string literal.

You need:

```
WHERE u.UserName IN (''' + @MemberNames + ''')
```

Alternately, you can leave your query as is, and seperate each ID with apostrophes in your `@MemberNames` variable:

```
SET @MemberName = '''cat'''           -- for a single user
SET @MemberName = '''cat'', ''dog'''  -- for multiple users
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass it as a string to the dynamic query

```
 SET @MemberNames = '''cat'''
```

Difference in the *`resulted query`* is

```
WHERE u.UserName IN (cat) -- cat is taking as a column name here
WHERE u.UserName IN ('cat') -- cat is taking as a string here
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dynamic query uses `'` characters as the string delimiter, so the last line ends up reading like this after the string is built:

```
WHERE u.UserName IN (cat)
```

According to this, `cat` reads like a column name.

To fix it, you need to include escaped `'` characters in either the definition of

```
`SET @MemberNames = '''cat'''`
```

or in the string being used to build the sql:

```
`WHERE u.UserName IN (''' + @MemberNames + ''')'`
```