# SQL Server Query using a Dynamic Column Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do a SQL query on a priority matrix. So I want to pass the column name dynamically and then also filter based on a where clause that also has a dynamic value.

I've found some answers on Stackoverflow that have been useful but they've only got me so far, and now I'm a bit stuck. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

**Query I have the issue with:**

```
DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @var2 VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(255)

SET @var1 = 'partial impact'
SET @var2 = 'single user'
SET @sql = 'select [' + @var1 + '] from [priority matrix] where impact is ['+ @var2 + ']'

EXECUTE(@sql);
```

Query that **isn't dynamic** and works fine:

```
SELECT [partial impact] 
FROM priorityMatrix 
WHERE impact = 'single user';
```

Error I'm seeing when I run it:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>     Incorrect syntax near 'single user'.

Stackoverflow queries that have helped so far:

[SQL Server + Dynamic Query 'Invalid Column Name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098268/sql-server-dynamic-query-invalid-column-name)
[How to set variable from a SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974683/how-to-set-variable-from-a-sql-query)

Comment: Have you tried to involve the equality symbol as you did in the *query that isn't dynamic*? Currently, you have an `is` there... In addition, the table name you are selecting from is not the same as it is in the working query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IS` <> `=`, so you need to fix it :

```
SET @sql = 'select [' + @var1 + '] from [priority matrix] where impact  = ['+ @var2 + ']';
```

I would use `QUOTENAME()` instead of manual `[]` :

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT '+ QUOTENAME(@var1) +' FROM [priority matrix] WHERE impact  = '''+@var2+'''';
```

*Literal* strings are quoted with single quotes, `[]` are not required.

Comment: It is not known if the value of `@var2` can be supplied by the end user. If so, any single quote characters in the value of `@var2` should be doubled (`'` -> `''`) to avoid SQL injection attacks: `WHERE impact = ''' + REPLACE(@var2, '''', '''''') + ''''`